# Turns 180 when it shouldn`t in Java

Tags: java, localization, location, game-physics

So I am trying to make the ghost(pinky) from pacman.But I am having problems with the movement. So I use getX() and getY() to determine where is pacman and therefore where the ghost should go.

However, the problems come when pacman is for example EAST and the ghost has headed WEST. Then when the ghost detects pacman X or Y it immediatelly turns 180.

Here is the code, you don`t need to read everything, it is similar. I am trying to cover every case.

```
import ch.aplu.jgamegrid.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.*;

public class Ghost extends Actor    

Set<Location.CompassDirection> random2SubDirs = new HashSet<Location.CompassDirection>();
    Location pakLocation = pakman.wherePakman();
    Location.CompassDirection dir = Location.EAST; 
    if (pakLocation.getX() > this.getLocation().getX()){
        dir = Location.EAST;
    }
    else if (pakLocation.getX() < this.getLocation().getX()){
        dir = Location.WEST;
    }
    else if (pakLocation.getY() > this.getLocation().getY()){
        dir = Location.SOUTH;
    }
    else if (pakLocation.getY() < this.getLocation().getY()){
        dir = Location.NORTH;
    }

    if (pakLocation.getX() == this.getLocation().getX()){
        if((pakLocation.getY() > this.getLocation().getY())){
            dir = Location.SOUTH;
        else if((pakLocation.getY() < this.getLocation().getY())){
            dir = Location.NORTH;
    }
    else if (pakLocation.getY() == this.getLocation().getY()){
        if((pakLocation.getX() > this.getLocation().getX())){
            dir = Location.EAST;
        else if((pakLocation.getX() < this.getLocation().getX())){
            dir = Location.WEST;
    }

    if (pakLocation.getY() > this.getLocation().getY() && pakLocation.getX() < this.getLocation().getX()){
        //southwest  
       random2SubDirs.add(Location.SOUTH);
       random2SubDirs.add(Location.WEST);
            int n = randomNumberGen.nextInt(2);
     System.out.println("southwest " + n);
            switch(n){
                case 0 : dir = Location.SOUTH;
                case 1 : dir = Location.WEST;
            }
     no180Turn(dir);
    }else if(pakLocation.getY() > this.getLocation().getY() && pakLocation.getX() > this.getLocation().getX()){
     //southeast   
       random2SubDirs.add(Location.SOUTH);
       random2SubDirs.add(Location.EAST);
            int n = randomNumberGen.nextInt(2);
       System.out.println("southeast " + n);
            switch(n){
                case 0 : dir = Location.SOUTH;
                case 1 : dir = Location.EAST;
            }
    }else if(pakLocation.getY() < this.getLocation().getY() && pakLocation.getX() < this.getLocation().getX()){
        //northwest
       random2SubDirs.add(Location.NORTH);
       random2SubDirs.add(Location.WEST);
            int n = randomNumberGen.nextInt(2);
       System.out.println("northwest " + n);
            switch(n){
                case 0 : dir = Location.NORTH;
                case 1 : dir = Location.WEST;
            } 
    }else if(pakLocation.getY() < this.getLocation().getY() && pakLocation.getX() > this.getLocation().getX()){
        //northeast
        random2SubDirs.add(Location.NORTH);
       random2SubDirs.add(Location.EAST);
            int n = randomNumberGen.nextInt(2);
       System.out.println("northeast " + n);
            switch(n){
                case 0 : dir = Location.NORTH;
                case 1 : dir = Location.EAST;
            }
    }
    if (fleeing){
        dir = oppositeDir(dir);
    }
    this.setDirection(dir);
    if (canMove(dir)){
        lastDir = dir;
        move();
    }else {randomMode = 10;
           System.out.println("now it is random");
    }
}
```

Is it in the IFs or I should make another method for this?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using enumerated directions (I'm assuming that's what the `NORTH`, `EAST`... are), why not just calculate the direction? You could do something like:

```
int xDifference = pakLocation.getX() - this.getLocation.getX();
```

Which gives you the distance from the ghost to the pakman along the x-axis, and includes a sign indicating direction (East or West in the case of the x coordinates).

Then, to get only the direction, use `signum`:

```
int xDirection = Math.signum(xDifference);
```

Which will return 1 (Go east), -1 (Go west), or 0 (Don't change lateral position). Then, if you need to adjust the speed, multiply `xDirection` by the amount you want the ghost to move per "tick". Then just duplicate the above 2 lines to deal with the y-axis.

This is undoubtedly far from perfect, but I think it allows for easier debugging. This won't directly solve your problem, but should make the movement logic simpler, which may help.

If anyone sees any issues in the logic, please comment and I'll update it.